# OWIN - signing and encrypting requests

Tags: asp.net, owin, adfs

In our asp.net MVC5 web site we're authenticating against multiple ADFS servers. One of these requests that we sign (and preferably encrypt) our request.

We're using OWIN and the UseWsFederationAuthentication extension method to set up the options for each ADFS server (see below).

```
var adfsLoginProviderOptions = new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
            {
                MetadataAddress = adfsLoginProvider.MetadataUrl,
                Wtrealm = AppSettings.FirstAgendaWtRealm,
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
                AuthenticationType = adfsLoginProvider.Name,
                CallbackPath = new PathString("/adfs/callback"),
                UseTokenLifetime = true
            };
app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(adfsLoginProviderOptions);
```

My problem is, I don't see a obvious option to set up request signing and encryption and I can't seem to find anyone else who has done this.

Comment: Hi. I am facing the same problem. Have you found a solution? Thanks.

Comment: I did actually. Will add a answer

Comment: Cool. Looking forward to that.

Answer (score 2):

I did some research and found the following.

I needed to register to SecurityTokenHandlers:

- One for decrypting the encrypted token
- One for validating the signed token

They are registered as follows:

```
    var adfsLoginProviderOptions = new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
            {
                MetadataAddress = adfsLoginProvider.MetadataUrl,
                Wtrealm = "http://[your-realm]",
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
                AuthenticationType = adfsLoginProvider.Name,
                UseTokenLifetime = false,
                CallbackPath = new PathString("/adfs/callback/" + adfsLoginProvider.ID.ToString()),
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    AuthenticationType = adfsLoginProvider.Name
                },
                SecurityTokenHandlers = new SecurityTokenHandlerCollection
                {
                    new EncryptedSecurityTokenHandler(new X509CertificateStoreTokenResolver(StoreName.My,StoreLocation.LocalMachine)),
                    new SamlSecurityTokenHandler
                    {
                        CertificateValidator = X509CertificateValidator.None,
                        Configuration = new SecurityTokenHandlerConfiguration()
                        {
                            AudienceRestriction = audienceRestriction,
                            IssuerNameRegistry = issuerRegistry
                        }
                    }
                },


            };
```

The EncryptedSecurityTokenHandler is implemented as follows:

```
        public class EncryptedSecurityTokenHandler : System.IdentityModel.Tokens.EncryptedSecurityTokenHandler, ISecurityTokenValidator
        {
            public EncryptedSecurityTokenHandler(SecurityTokenResolver securityTokenResolver)
            {
                Configuration = new SecurityTokenHandlerConfiguration
                {
                    ServiceTokenResolver = securityTokenResolver
                };
            }

            public override bool CanReadToken(string securityToken)
            {
                return base.CanReadToken(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(securityToken)));
            }

            public ClaimsPrincipal ValidateToken(string securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken)
            {
                // Read token will decrypt it and look for another SecurityTokenHandler in the same collection to do the actual validation
                validatedToken = ReadToken(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(securityToken)), Configuration.ServiceTokenResolver);
                if (ContainingCollection != null)
                {
                    var identities = ContainingCollection.ValidateToken(validatedToken);
                    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identities.First());
                    return principal;
                }
                return new ClaimsPrincipal(base.ValidateToken(validatedToken));
            }

            public int MaximumTokenSizeInBytes { get; set; }
        }
```

And the SamlSecurityTokenHandler:

```
public class SamlSecurityTokenHandler : System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SamlSecurityTokenHandler, ISecurityTokenValidator
{
    public override bool CanReadToken(string securityToken)
    {
        return base.CanReadToken(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(securityToken)));
    }

    public ClaimsPrincipal ValidateToken(string securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters,
        out SecurityToken validatedToken)
    {
        validatedToken = ReadToken(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(securityToken)), Configuration.ServiceTokenResolver);
        var identities = ValidateToken(validatedToken);
        var newIdentities = identities.Select(d => new ClaimsIdentity(d.Claims, "ExternalCookie"));
        var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(newIdentities);
        return claimsPrincipal; ;
    }

    public override ReadOnlyCollection<ClaimsIdentity> ValidateToken(SecurityToken token)
    {
        var identities = base.ValidateToken(token);
        return identities
    }

    public int MaximumTokenSizeInBytes { get; set; }
}
```

Audience restriction is the realm of the application:

```
var audienceRestriction = new AudienceRestriction(AudienceUriMode.Always);
audienceRestriction.AllowedAudienceUris.Add(new Uri(http://[your-realm]));
```

IssuerRegistry is the registry of the issuer signing certificates:

```
var issuerRegistry = new ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry();
issuerRegistry.AddTrustedIssuer(adfsLoginProvider.SigningCertThumbprint, adfsLoginProvider.Issuer);
```